# Ubuntu Touch (of Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition) freezes when booting up

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone

After I fully charged and rebooted my Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, it freezed instantly. I am not able to complete any touch gesture.

pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkCl2.jpg

When I try to boot 'recovery' (Volume Up + Power), it will boot regularly without any change.

Can I reset my phone by connecting it via USB to an PC??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The standard recovery image does not permit adb access, so you need to supply one to ubuntu-device-flash which will allow adb to work. This image is a good choice:

http://people.canonical.com/~jhm/barajas/recovery.img

You can then type

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --bootstrap --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --recovery-image recovery.img
```

Which will reset your phone (including a data wipe!) to factory state.

Answer (score -1):

Try recovery with [wipe/data factory reset option during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5/602037#602037) before flashing device from image. I had to do this on same new phone :-(

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).