# Can't use ubuntu-device-flash

Tags: ubuntu-touch, flash

Whenever I use `ubuntu-device-flash` on my BQ Aquaris e4.5 I get this:

```
root@finlay-afr:/home/finlay# ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap
2015/04/25 10:40:28 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/04/25 10:40:28 Device is |1|
2015/04/25 10:40:28 Device 1 not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: managed to get progress by using `ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --device=krillin` but now I get stuck with this:

```
2015/04/25 14:35:20 Device is |krillin|
2015/04/25 14:35:21 Flashing version 21 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
2015/04/25 14:35:21 ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09 is a channel alias to ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
67.41 MB / 67.41 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 1.70 MB/s 
60.40 MB / 60.40 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 1.48 MB/s 
286.68 MB / 286.68 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 2.94 MB/s 
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-21.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz
/root/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-0142302186687e3e48e6987283f6caf5d471a4160f98aa6a3cb7658f96471297.tar.xz
2015/04/25 14:37:18 Can't flash recovery image
```

how do I fix that?
5/11/2015: still not working, anyone help >.>

Comment: anyone? please?

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5/602037#602037

Comment: Galgalesh, the solutian you gave me isn't working because of error `Can't flash recovery image`