# How to install latest ubuntu-device-flash in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to follow the instructions to [flash my bq phone](https://askubuntu.com/a/602037/172367) when I get the following error:

```
$ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery.img
unknown flag `recovery-image'
```

I'm guessing this is because the the ubuntu-device-flash package on ubuntu 14.04 is outdated? How do I install the latest version?

Comment: I think you want to give the complete path to your recovery image to `--recovery-image`

Comment: Ron, that gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the latest `ubuntu-device-flash` using the ppa:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools 
 sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash
```

When trying to update, the `ubuntu-device-flash` might be held back. If this is the case, you can upgrade that package using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: as of june 2016 these instructions do not work, the package does not exist in the supplied ppa's

Comment: @grandrew, strange, it seems to work on my device. Are you sure you executed `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: yes sure, I tired everything. At last I just installed a 16.04 chroot to get the latest package.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to do `sudo apt-get update` after each request for repository. Try the following I Galgalesh, method but did `sudo apt-get update` after the repository request. See Below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash && sudo apt-get update
```