# BQ Aquaris 4.5 dosn't boot after OTA-4

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris

I wanted to install the new Ubutnu Touch update this morning but as I had to reboot the phone there was a massege like "This device needs to be restored from a PC"
So i tried to connect it to my PC but this didn't worked. I tried to restart the phone again. This time it only shows me a screen with "bq powered by ubuntu" . I am waiting for over 40 minutes now but nothing more happends.

What can i do now to reset my phony ?

Comment: if you're happy to factory reset, this answer covers you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5/602037

Comment: You can use other options with ubuntu-device-flash if you want to attempt to preserve your userdata.

Comment: Are you set up in developer mode, and have used apt-get update? That's been long a dangerous path with OTA updates, and it seems this OTA has finally caused a severe problem with this practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to say you're not the only one... It happened to me too yesterday as soon as I saw the update was available. At this point you cannot just reset your phone, what you need is to re-install ubuntu-touch (at least that's what it sounds like from your description). I cannot speak from experience because I don't have the time to bring mine back to life, but here are all the instructions on how to do this:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/