# Ubuntu Phone (Touch) lock screen issue after upgrade to OS 23

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, phone, lock

After updating my Aquarius 4.5 to OS 23 (Build Ubuntu 15.04 armhf), the screen won't auto lock. It's forever on and the phone is heating. However, if I manually press the power bottom, the screen turns off and locks.

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour. Is it possible you're using a configuration that has not been tested, because your filesystem was writeable, and additional packages have been installed?

Comment: Hi, John. It's possible, I guess. But how can I be sure and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: I have restored the system, but the same OS 23 was instaled, It didn't downgrade. The problems persists. I suppose this is a version problem.

Comment: unless you performed a factory reset & wipe (like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5), for example), then there can still be leftovers from when your system was writeable.

Comment: I experience exactly the same with MX4. Running 15.04 r2, I did set 'autolock screen' to 'never' for a short while. This is pretty annoying as the phone also doesn't charge as quickly when the screen is on, and the screen unlocks when plugged in. The only thing I changed when the file system was r/w was change the APN settings.