# BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition: Downgrade to Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq, aquaris

Is it possible to install Android on the BQ E4.5 UE and reinstall Ubuntu Touch later when some important apps are available?

How to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Yes - it is possible to downgrade it to android and you can follow this guide - http://a25.co/ubuntu-phone-how-to-install-android/ (which is not written by me).

Some of the information there is a bit outdated (the latest android for the phone at this moment is Lollipop) but the basic principle is the same.

As for reverting back to Ubuntu Touch - it is possible but I haven't tried it yet and can't be of much help with that. I think the procedure would be the same as with the android install, just using the Ubuntu firmware provided at the BQ site instead.

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the linked guide. It is indeed possible to reinstall Ubuntu Touch later using a similar method as installing Android using the MediaTek tool (Linux/Windows) or using `ubuntu-device-flash`. See this discussion: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5