# install O.S. on MEIZU MX4 ubuntu edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am french and my english level is not fluently.

I am an user of ubuntu (xubuntu, lubuntu) on P.C. since many years and i like the personnalisation of this operating system.

I am owner since one month of MEIZU MX4 Ubuntu edition and italian meizu seller didn't send documentation.

My questions: what is the process to install the O.S. after a crash problem? the warranty is not all the life!!!

is it possible to manage the phone from the PC terminal to install/remove/clean the cache etc... ?

Thank you for your help

Best regards

Joël LE DURELIC

Comment: With BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition you start the phone in fastboot mode  and run `phablet-flash` (http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5/602037#602037) I do not have a Meizu. Maybe, the procedure is similar.