# How to upgrade my Aquarius E4.5 to latest OS?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 14.10, bq

I took my bq from the shelf. Have not touched it for a while, it is more or  less in ship state.

Currently it runs 14.10(r21)
I cannot find any way to upgrade. What do I have to do? It is currently almost useless, as most apps won't start. I was hoping an update would help.

It does tell me that 35 apps can be upgraded, but it does not actually upgrade them, download works, but they stay in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally turned out, that after several hours, reboots and checking for updates, the device eventually found a system update available.

After downloading and pressing install it rebooted and hung up after a while. Letting it in that state for more than hour (just to be sure) and hard restart it booted up again, now with 15.04 (OTA-9.1).

Seems like it is difficult to wake up a phone after 1.5 years, but finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, as this isn't a full answer, but [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5) (elsewhere on askubuntu), you can see how to manually flash (and update) your phone (I have never actually done it myself, though).

You could also (first) trying playing around with when updates are supposed to be downloaded (always/only on wifi/never) which is also determined under Settings > Updates.

Comment: That is a good general hint, thanks. My problem was solved otherwise, I will add an own answer for it. :)