# Install Ubuntu touch on production devices

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, recovery-mode, adb

Reading at the wiki here [ubuntu touch install wiki](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) and going to see the supported devices I read that for the "production" devices (like mine meizu pro 5) an adb enabled recovery should be present on the device, as better explained here [Adb enabled recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5)  
My question is: have I to install this recovery only if I need manual update/channel shift, or it's a mandatory part to complete the installation process with ubuntu-device-flash command for my device?

thanks 
luckj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recovery is only needed if you want to flash the device with ubuntu-device-flash. If you use system-image-cli directly on the device to switch channel, then the recovery image isn't required.