# ubuntu-device-flash not working with BQ Aquaris E5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 to try and flash my (currently) Android phone with Ubuntu Touch. All was going well until I tried to use `ubuntu-device-flash` which doesn't seem to be working.
I am using the latest version from `ppa:phablet-team/tools`
The phone is a BQ Aquaris E5, and I have booted it into the bootloader.
`adb` says the device is `|MSM8916|` but there doesn't seem to be an image for this, so I have been trying to use `|vegetahd|` instead.

`$ sudo ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --device=vegetahd
2016/07/19 21:41:36 Device is |vegetahd|
2016/07/19 21:41:36 Flashing version 13 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device vegetahd
67.93 MB / 67.93 MB [=====================================================>_] 100.00 % 239.00 KB/s 
70.78 MB / 70.78 MB [=======================================================] 100.00 % 225.58 KB/s 
293.25 MB / 293.25 MB [=====================================================] 100.00 % 533.47 KB/s 
Can't boot recovery image`

This thread suggests giving `ubuntu-device-flash` an explicit recovery image.

[How do I use ubuntu-device-flash with the BQ Aquaris E4.5 and Aquaris E5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5)

I've tried that, but I get exactly the same. `ubuntu-device-flash` is just totally ignoring the `--recovery-image` argument: I get exactly the same output whether or not I give it an image file that exists.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

your phone, I’m afraid, has the wrong chip set, see also my statement here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843973/attention-dont-buy-bq-aquaris-e5-with-a-wrong-chip-set

Volker