# BQ Aquaris E5 -> Device MSM8916 not found

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris, bq

presently I purchased a BQ Aquaris E5 phone in a second hand shop with android on it.

After typing in a console:

```
volker@v____50:~$ sudo ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
2016/10/30 17:41:10 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/10/30 17:41:10 Device is |MSM8916|
Device MSM8916 not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
volker@v____50:~$
```

Who can I solve the problem? I don’t want to use a google operating system ;-)

Thanks 
Volker

Comment: What Android version are you on?

Comment: I don't know the Android Version, I don't have any experience with Android.

Comment: Go to Settings > About phone.  It will tell you the Android version there.

Answer (score 0):

i've recently bought the same phone and had the same problem.

you originally posted an answer elsewhere, about this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/843977/381059
but unfortunately it is now gone.

unfortunately, and quite irrationally, like various other companies, **BQ have actually released various products with the same name but with substantially different components inside.**

as you can see there are two BQ phones which include the name 'aquaris E5' that have the same hardware:
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/05f034d3
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/741b30e5

but there are another two which include the name 'aquaris E5' with different hardware, the newer one especially so ! 
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/a75230e6
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/ad803119

for a full comparison of all of them:
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/comparison/d2aca7254

Answer (score 0):

The E5s is a different chipset and not supported. Only the original Aquaris E5 HD with MediaTek chipset (vegetahd device name) is supported.