# Boot process on Ubuntu Touch on Aquaris 4.5 only shows Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch

After change language settings on my Aquaris 4.5 from German to English, my device refuses to boot.

Stays in boot loop, only showing the small Ubuntu logo.

Some questions, according to this issue, come close to mine:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/538102/can-no-longer-boot-into-ubuntu-touch-on-nexus-7

[Ubuntu Touch (of Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition) freezes when booting up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598797/ubuntu-touch-of-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition-freezes-when-booting-up)

I have tried to flash stock rom image multiple times.

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash --clean-cache touch
2015/04/02 12:59:48 Cleaning prevously downloaded content
.
$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --bootstrap --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
2015/04/02 13:00:03 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/04/02 13:00:03 Device is |krillin|
2015/04/02 13:00:03 Flashing version 20 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
56.98 MB / 56.98 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 4.40 MB/s 
67.30 MB / 67.30 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 3.99 MB/s 
286.36 MB / 286.36 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 8.05 MB/s
Failed to enter Recovery
```

After flash process, device reboots with a purple background and a big white/orange Ubuntu logo. After 2 minutes, the BQ boot screen appears.
Now only the little Ubuntu logo is shown, turning... (over 8 hours)

If I try to flash recovery image (shown in [Ubuntu Touch (of Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition) freezes when booting up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598797/ubuntu-touch-of-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition-freezes-when-booting-up)) following happens:

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery.img
2015/04/02 13:12:22 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/04/02 13:12:29 Device is |krillin|
2015/04/02 13:12:29 Flashing version 20 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
Failed to enter Recovery
```

Any suggestions ???

Regards.

PS: 
I have followed this thread:
[How do I use ubuntu-device-flash with the BQ Aquaris E4.5 and Aquaris E5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5)

Comment: See : http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-aquaris-e5